# How to stack multiple carousel components on a single page in React?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-bootstrap, react-component

In my React app I want to include 3 image carousels stacked on top of each other on a single page. I'm using a carousel component from React-Bootstrap which renders some image files saved locally in the public folder.

[Here is a link to the source code from Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/carousel/)

TIA!

PS: Please explain your answer to me step-by-step as if you were talking to a 5 year old! I'm a complete beginner to coding and don't yet recognise most jargon!

Comment: Why can't you try for yourself this?
"If I want to stack 3 carousels I assume I can't just copy+paste the same code 3 times??"

I would suggest that you try first with your idea and then look for answers with better coding standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assumptions for my example:**

- I used 3 stacked carousels with 3 images each
- Images are cycled through (if you reach first or last you "jump" to the other side)
- Carousel images have no captions

**Setup UI and config the carousel**:

- Use an outer vertical stack to stack your slider/button sections and the go-back button
- Use an inner horizontal stack to stack your two buttons and the slider
- Configure each carousel as following:

.

```
<Carousel
    controls={false}
    indicators={false}
    interval={null}
    activeIndex={slidersState[x]}
>
```

- controls=false will hide the arrows on each side.
- indicators=false will hider the "strokes" in the middle of the carousel.
- interval=null will deactivate automatic sliding.

**Define the state and impement the logic:**

You will need such state, that can manage every of your carousel. In my example I'm giving every carousel an id and set the state to the first image (=0). Write two button onClick handlers - for going forward and back:

```
const initialSlidersState = {
    1: 0,
    2: 0,
    3: 0
};
const [slidersState, setSlidersState] = React.useState(initialSlidersState);

const nextSlide = (sliderId) => setSlidersState((prev) => {
  const currentIndex = prev[sliderId];
  let newIndex;
  if (currentIndex === 2) {
    newIndex = 0;
  } else {
    newIndex = currentIndex + 1;
  }
  return { ...prev, [sliderId]: newIndex };
});

const previousSlide = (sliderId) => setSlidersState((prev) => {
  const currentIndex = prev[sliderId];
  let newIndex;
  if (currentIndex === 0) {
    newIndex = 2;
  } else {
    newIndex = currentIndex - 1;
  }
  return { ...prev, [sliderId]: newIndex };
});
```

Of course this already works with dynamic amount of sliders and dynamic amount of images, but for the sake of simplicity I have used fixed amounts. For the buttons you could alternatively deactivate them, when reaching first/last image. Finally, you could also adopt the native controls from the carousel component, but it would go too far for this simple example.

Please look into following code sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-matsumoto-f8j1zf

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much! I feel like I understand the logic a bit better. I really appreciate you taking the effort to explain in so much detail :)